# ManyToManyField and South migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have user profile model with M2M field

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Now I need to know HOW and WHEN add each other as a FRIEND
And I created a model for that

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True, through="Relationship")
    ...


class Relationship(models.Model):    
    """ Friends """        
    from_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="relationship_set_from_account")            
    to_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="relationship_set_to_account")
    # ... some special fields for friends relationship

    class Meta:                    
        db_table = "accounts_account_friends"            
        unique_together = ('from_account','to_account')
```

Should I create any migration for this changes or not ?
If you have any suggestions you are feel free write their here.

Thanks

PS: `accounts_account` table already contain records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I'd avoid using the `db_table` alias if you can. This makes it harder to understand the table structure, as it is no longer in sync with the models.

Secondly, the South API offers functions like `db.rename_table()`, which can be used by manually editing the migration file. You can rename the `accounts_account_friends` table to `accounts_relation` (as Django would name it by default), and add the additional columns.

This combined gives you the  following migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # the Account.friends field is a many-to-many field which got a through= option now.
    # Instead of dropping+creating the table (or aliasing in Django),
    # rename it, and add the required columns.

    # Rename table
    db.delete_unique('accounts_account_friends', ['from_account', 'to_account'])
    db.rename_table('accounts_account_friends', 'accounts_relationship')

    # Add extra fields
    db.add_column('accounts_relationship', 'some_field',  ...)

    # Restore unique constraint
    db.create_unique('accounts_relationship', ['from_account', 'to_account'])


def backwards(self, orm):

    # Delete columns
    db.delete_column('accounts_relationship', 'some_field')
    db.delete_unique('accounts_relationship', ['from_account', 'to_account'])

    # Rename table
    db.rename_table('accounts_relationship', 'accounts_account_friends')
    db.create_unique('accounts_account_friends', ['from_account', 'to_account'])


models = {
    # Copy this from the final-migration.py file, see below
}
```

The unique relation is removed, and recreated so the constraint has the proper name.

The add column statements are easily generated with the following trick:

- Add the `Relationship` model in `models.py` with foreign key fields only, and no changes to the M2M field yet.
- Migrate to it
- Add the fields to the `Relationship` model.
- Do a `./manage.py schemamigration app --auto --stdout | tee final-migration.py | grep column`
- Revert the first migration.

Then you have everything you need to construct the migration file.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've got it coded there, you're manually defining a model which does the same job as the m2m join table that Django will have automatically created for you. The thing is, the automatically created table will be called `accounts_relationship_friend`.

So, what you're doing there will create a model that tries to duplicate what the ORM has done under the surface, but it's pointing at the wrong table.

If you don't need an explicit join model, I would leave remove it from your codebase and not create a migration to add it, and instead use the M2M to find relationships between friends. (I'm not thinking about this too deeply, but it should work).

If, however, you want to do something special with the Relationship model you have (eg store attributes about the type of relationship, etc), I would declare the Relationship model to be the through model you use in your Friend.friends m2m definition. [See the docs here.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I have model with m2m field `friends` and there are profiles in the DB. Now I want to add some special property to Relation ship (creation date, or etc.). And I create `trough` table. And I want to know: should I do migration or not for this case. 
You answer contain good information but as you can see I'm already done this.